# Axios Error - HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT error "Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/"

Tags: javascript, axios

curl -v --location 'http://api.mast.com/webservice/fourthparty/content/apple/fallback?content_id=236&product=EEF' --header 'PRODUCT: EEF' | hexdump -C

Trying to make the same call using POSTMAN and Axios(JS code), they are not able to parse the response when **https** is used in URL

```
Error : HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT error "Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/"
```

204 returned by a server
, curl works fine on terminal

hexdump of the response is 0 bytes in both the cases.

Response of the HTTP call on Terminal

```
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Cache-Control: max-age=0
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Fri, 05 Jan 2024 14:20:52 GMT
< Server: nginx/1.10.3
< Via: 1.1 google
< X-Cache: BYPASS
< x-edgecast-rewrite: /80E/api.mast.com/webservice/fourthparty/content/apple/fallback
< x-edgecast-rules: 0.57K11-v14
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
< 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host api.mast.com left intact
```

Response of HTTPS call on Terminal

```
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
< cache-control: max-age=0
< content-type: application/json
< date: Fri, 05 Jan 2024 14:20:43 GMT
< server: nginx/1.10.3
< via: 1.1 google
< x-cache: BYPASS
< x-edgecast-rewrite: /80E/api.mast.com/webservice/fourthparty/content/apple/fallback
< x-edgecast-rules: 0.57K11-v14
< x-powered-by: PHP/5.4.45
< 
{ [0 bytes data]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host api.mast.com left intact
```

Is the parsing issue due to a different version of HTTP protocol or encoding with HTTPS or some header causing the issue or something else ?

Comment: "api.mast.com" is not exist , how to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue as it an internal domain to my organisation.

Comment: The origin server  uses nginx as proxy. Can it intercept the request and send a different response only for specific HTTP codes

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.